# Java: File path error

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javafx

```
File defaultCss=new File(this.getClass().getResource("application.css").getFile());

PiChart.getScene().getStylesheets().add("file:///" + defaultCss.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/"));
```

The above line in Controller.java fetches the required resource in Eclipse while running, but when exported to an executable JAR, it is not fetching the file.

Because:
In **Eclipse** the line fetches
`src/com/piscope/application.css`

In **JAR**, the path is:
`com/piscope/application.css`

Please let me know the path to be set so that one can run both eclipse and JAR executions without errors.
 
**Note:** Since the file is the source for the software package,the file needs to be inside the JAR file.

Comment: Don't try and access classpath resources as file objects in general

Comment: I have two css files. The default one which resides in source folder and is only accessed. The latter is placed outside the source and is modified when application preferences are changed. If the latter is placed inside the source folder, as you mentioned it cannot be modified. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following (no need to format the syntax by yourself):

```
PiChart.getScene().getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: The above is the default method by which the start() loads the css file. Thank you for your reply.